# Iframe acting as new session, no access to existing cache/not saving cache to main browser

Tags: php, session, caching, iframe, browser-cache

I've got a CMS where I have recently created a function to 'Login as' for debugging purposes. Though I would also like to keep the admin account in the cache/active. My original thought was to make use of an incognito mode in browsers but have now found that it can not be called from the web page.

Is there a way of loading an iframe as a fresh session, like an incognito mode in a browser?

Edit:
Another approach would be sending POST data through a hyperlink. I can do this into a 'normal' tab using Jquery but it just loads the default about page when I right click and opt to open as an incognito tab.

Any other solutions or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have control of the front end and back end code, you could modify things so that if the URL is called with nocache and nocookies arguments, it doesn't use cached or stored data. Then call the url in the iframe with these arguments set.

Answer (score 0):

No. There is not sadly, though you can just open up a session in a different tab.